# Why does my post request for fileupload work on Postman but not in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

My React.js project and Laravel project are separated.

1. I login as an authenticated user in Postman using this endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login`)
2. I then upload a file using this (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame`)

All works fine - user's logged in and that logged in user can successfully upload a file to the db along with their `user_id`, `email`, and `file_path`.

The only thing that's very very weird about this working's that I'm not using an access token to successfully upload the aforementioned data to the db in Postman.

However, when I try the above 2 steps on the browser - I get a `200` when checking the Network tab but nothing's being stored in the db.  I'm using an access token because how else can I recognize an authenticated on the client side?

Since this process works in Postman, my inclination's that something's off with the frontend and my possibly my Axios call.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            email: email
        })
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ selectedFile: e.target.files }, () => this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13,-8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        console.log(this.state.id); // returns correct currently logged in userid
        console.log(this.state.email); // returns correct currently logged in user email address
        formData.append('file',file);

        const headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit" >Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's backend controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Photo;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = Auth::user();

//        dd($user);

        if($user) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $email = Auth::user()->email;
            $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'email' => $email
            ];
            DB::table('db.photos')->insert($data);
            return "inserted successfully";
        }

    return "failed";

    }
}
```

Comment: Postman might work if the backend writes a cookie that gets sent with the following request. I can't see from your example how the authentication bit is supposed to work though. What's the response body you're getting back? It's status 200, but is the content "inserted successfully" or "failed"?

Comment: @Timo In Postman it's `inserted successfully` but on the browser it's `failed`.

Comment: Okay in that case whatever sets the value on this line: `$user = Auth::user();` is going to be falsy. Your authentication fails but it's difficult to tell from the example what actually is going wrong in there. You should check if the token gets passed correctly and if your backend is able to read and validate it.